# Rails 3 + MongoDB: Render Json Without a Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

```
    render :json => @bs.to_a.to_json, :except => ["completo"]
```

I want to render everything to json except the field "completo". That should be working but given that I need to do ".to_a" and ".to_json", that stopped working. Is there a way to revert that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that @bs is a MongoDB Cursor, do the following:

```
@bs = @bs.to_a.map { |obj| obj.delete("completo"); obj }
render :json => @bs.to_json
```

In summary:

1. Make it an array.
2. Remove the `completo` key from every item in the array, making sure we return the item itself at the end of the `map`
3. Render as before.

Comment: I'm not sure the `to_json` call is required, but I left it in anyways.